NextAuthとnext-i18n-routerの共存
Next.jsを使っていて、認証と多言語対応が必要です。
しかし両者を共存させることができなくて困っています。
認証にはNextAuthを、多言語対応でルーティングのライブラリとしてnext-i18n-routerを使用しています。
どちらもNext.jsのミドルウェアで設定が必要です。
NextAuthでは、以下のようにwithAuthをデフォルトでエクスポートする必要があります。
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware"

export default withAuth({
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
    error: "/error",
  },
})

next-i18n-routerでは以下のように自作のミドルウェアでレスポンスをラップする必要があります。
import { i18nRouter } from 'next-i18n-router';
import i18nConfig from './i18nConfig';

export function middleware(request) {
  return i18nRouter(request, i18nConfig);
}

どちらも使いたいのですが、両者を共存させるにはどのように書けばいいのでしょうか？
